# Advantages and downsides of moving the _tmp directory to RAM disk in order to increase MongoDB aggregation performance

Tags: mongodb, caching, aggregation-framework, ram

I know that Mongodb uses the _tmp directory for some operations as an aggregation that exceeds 100MB or index creation.

Wouldn't there be a great performance improvement if the content of _tmp was put into RAM cache disk rather than on the disk itself?
And if so, what are the downsides and restrictions of such approach?

Comment: Why don't you try that out?

Comment: a quick and simple test on an aggregation with 1M of documents:

`db.onemilion.aggregate([{$addFields:{ d: { $add : ["$d", "$c"]}}}, {$sort: {d: -1}}], {allowDiskUse:true})`: Without ramdisk ~ 9600 ms, With ramdisk: ~ 5700 ms But I don't know if there may be problems on a production server ... for example it seems that temporary files are not deleted at the end of the operation

Comment: The idea of using disk as aggregation spillover is to make it not compete for RAM with other things the server needs to do. Moving this `_tmp` directory to RAM would (kind of) defeats this purpose. This would of course depend on your workload, but the less than stellar result you had may point to other work the aggregation needs to do and it was not really bottlenecked on `_tmp` disk use.